# Building strings from sqlite3 databse in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'd like to write a JS script what works with nodejs and operates on sqlite3 database. The plan is to get data from the database and surrounding with "script" tags. My snippet is the following:

```
var sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
var db = new sqlite3.Database('/var/www/db/js.sqlite');

var MyRandomCode =
{
    code: "<script>"
}

function appendToCode(snippet) {
    MyRandomCode.code += snippet;
}

function printMe() {
    console.log(MyRandomCode.code);
}

function closeCode() {
    MyRandomCode.code += "</script>";
}

printMe();
randomNode("defun", MyRandomCode);
printMe();
closeCode();

function randomNode(name, MyRandomCode) {
    db.get("SELECT tag_value FROM tags WHERE tag_name=\"" + name + "\"", function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        appendToCode(rows['tag_value']);
    });
}
```

The database only contains a "test" function implementation.
The expected result is:

```
<script>
function test() {
    a = 5;
    c += a + b;
    "foo";
    var foo = 5;
    const bar = 6, baz = 7;
    switch ("foo") {
      case "foo":
        return 1;
      case "bar":
        return 2;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        console.log("Hello " + i);
    }
    for (var i in [ 1, 2, 3 ]) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) console.log("foo");
}
</script>
```

In spite of this i got

```
<script></script>function test() {
    a = 5;
    c += a + b;
    "foo";
    var foo = 5;
    const bar = 6, baz = 7;
    switch ("foo") {
      case "foo":
        return 1;
      case "bar":
        return 2;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        console.log("Hello " + i);
    }
    for (var i in [ 1, 2, 3 ]) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) console.log("foo");
}
```

I don't understand why is the order of the strings changed. Why isn't the function string inside the "script" tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.get` is an asynch operation, so `closeCode` will run before the DB operation has finished.

You should move `closeCode` and `printMe` into the async operation so they run after the db update works:

```
function randomNode(name, MyRandomCode) {
    db.get("SELECT tag_value FROM tags WHERE tag_name=\"" + name + "\"", function(err, rows) {
        if (err) throw err;
        appendToCode(rows['tag_value']);
        closeCode();
        printMe();
    });
}
```